# Why does Winrar eat up all free space?

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, winrar

I have about 35 gb free on my Windows 10 partition. I have a rar file that will extract to about 25 gb. When I try to extract it using Winrar, it ends up taking up all space on my hard drive despite there being enough space. Attempting to find out where the space is going fails. As far as I know there is no temp file being created since I am extracting directly to the extraction location.
There is a large dissonance between the sum of the folders in the drive and the used up space. How do I fix this?
[image]

Comment: I really suspect that claim about no temp file

Comment: That's what my original problem was, but I discovered the temp file using windirstat and found a way to skip the creation of a temp file in winrar. Now, however, when running Windirstat, instead of a giant temp file being created, only one big file in the correct location is created, but the "size" of the C: drive in windirstat gets smaller, from 45 gb to 35 gb, in the process of extraction. This is confusing me more than a little bit.

Comment: Did you run Windirstat as Admin? Becuase it might be it still creates a temp file just in a location Windirstat cannot access not as admin.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this problem by setting the Path of the temporary files to the Desktop. WinRAR created a temp folder in the Desktop called "Rar$DRa1488.27961", but it didn't put any temp files inside it. Everything works normally now. So somehow it fixed itself? Putting this answer here so that I see it when I forget this in a week or two.

Comment: You also could have used a sandboxing program like Sandboxie which tells you the paths the sandboxed program interacted with.